# keyctl disables VMVware CPU

Tags: centos, vmware

I'm having a little difficulty in understanding how `keyctl` operates, specifically the `request2` function. As I understand it, `request2` will attempt to search for the given string, and if found return it. If not found it call the `/sbin/request-key` application which will execute the operation described by `/etc/request-key.d/*` and `/etc/request-key.conf` (as applicable).

However, in testing this I have run into some issues.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/request-key.conf
###############################################################################
#
# Copyright (C) 2005 Red Hat, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
...snip... 
###############################################################################

#OP     TYPE    DESCRIPTION     CALLOUT INFO    PROGRAM ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ...
#====== ======= =============== =============== ===============================
create  dns_resolver *          *               /sbin/key.dns_resolver %k
create  user    debug:*         negate          /bin/keyctl negate %k 30 %S
create  user    debug:*         rejected        /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:*         expired         /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:*         revoked         /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:loop:*    *               |/bin/cat
create  user    debug:*         *               /usr/share/keyutils/request-key-debug.sh %k %d %c %S
negate  *       *               *               /bin/keyctl negate %k 30 %S
[user@localhost ~]$
```

Create a debug loop which will create a real key, `keyctl print` will generate the correct output.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl request2 user debug:loop:test "loop test"
181348864
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl show
Session Keyring
 141395006 --alswrv   1000  1000  keyring: _ses
 521399390 --alswrv   1000 65534   \_ keyring: _uid.1000
 181348864 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:loop:test
 691271691 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:test
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl print 181348864
loop test
[user@localhost ~]$
```

Create another key which will create a debug entry per `request-key.conf`. `keyctl print` correctly prints the key.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl request2 user debug:se-test "hello hello"
1061018025
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl show
Session Keyring
 141395006 --alswrv   1000  1000  keyring: _ses
 521399390 --alswrv   1000 65534   \_ keyring: _uid.1000
1061018025 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:se-test
 181348864 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:loop:test
 691271691 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:test
[user@localhost ~]$
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl print 1061018025
Debug hello hello
[user@localhost ~]$
```

Create a key that does not match any other rule, should create a negative key. `keyctl print` triggers a CPU disabled in VMWare forcing a reset.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl request2 user se:test "blah"
request_key: Required key not available
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl show
Session Keyring
 141395006 --alswrv   1000  1000  keyring: _ses
 521399390 --alswrv   1000 65534   \_ keyring: _uid.1000
  65104736 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: se:test
1061018025 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:se-test
 181348864 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:loop:test
 691271691 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:test
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl desc 65104736
 65104736: alswrv-----v------------  1000  1000 user: se:test
[user@localhost ~]$
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl print 65104736
```

Create a negative debug key, `keyctl print` triggers the same as above.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl request2 user debug:negatetest negate
request_key: Required key not available
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl show
Session Keyring
1018725144 --alswrv   1000  1000  keyring: _ses
 478030378 --alswrv   1000 65534   \_ keyring: _uid.1000
 799585275 --alswrv   1000  1000   \_ user: debug:negatetest
[user@localhost ~]$
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl desc 799585275
799585275: alswrv-----v------------  1000  1000 user: debug:negatetest
[user@localhost ~]$ keyctl print 799585275
```

In attempting to read (what should be) the negative key the OS just spontaneously shuts down.

As I understand it, a negative key cannot be read, however, is an immediate OS power-off the expected result?

The specific error I get is the following:

> The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or
>   reset the virtual machine.

I've gone through the documentation of `request-key.conf`, `keyctl(1)` and `keyctl(2)`, but was unable to find something. If I missed something, feel free to point me to the relevant portion and RTFM me.

Thanks!